# Yarn keeps telling me to rename folder

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Yesterday, yarn worked just fine, but today yarn absolutely refuses to work. Running any kind of yarn command fails.

```
Internal Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\NAME\.node\corepack\corepack-4304-ea1e7c84.0eb04' -> 'C:\Users\NAME\.node\corepack\yarn\3.1.1'
```

I tried following the instructions.

I also noticed that the referenced .node folder was read-only. This is weird because every time I try to use yarn, the corepack-RANDOMSTRING is a new folder.

Removing read-only from the folder and checking if it has been removed says it is read only again.

Comment: Is it **telling you** to rename the folder, or is it complaining that the operation was not permitted when **it tried** to rename the folder?

Comment: @Wyck indeed. I am fully aware of that. Yet it also happens when running as administrator

Comment: The `rename` isn't imperative, it's the name of the operation that failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure you are running the CMD prompt as `Administrator`
2. Then install Yarn
   `npm install --global yarn`
3. Verify that Yarn installed correctly
   `yarn --version`
   It should print the version number.

If that doesn't work try adding the `--force` flag as @sfuqua mentions in the comments so `npm install --global yarn --force`

**Note:**
Reading through this article https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/992 It looks like there are many reasons why this could occur.

Comment: thank you very very much. It seems that yarn somehow auto-updated and the newest version is broken for me.

Comment: After trying many things, including getting an antivirus exclusion on `C:\Users\NAME\.node\corepack`, using `npm install --global yarn --force` was the first thing that actually worked, enabling me to install yarn 3.x.